# Kernel module assembly output

Tags: linux, kernel, c, modules, assembly

I compiled the kernel modules written in C directly on my Raspberry Pi using this Makefile:

```
obj-m := HelloWorld.o

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I was wondering how to get the compiler to output the assembly source code.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If so, please mark the answer that helped you, or if you solved it on your own, create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and marking answers is what does that. If you resolved it and mark then people in the future will be able to profit from what you did *and* it helps move the site closer to graduation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your C compiler?

If it's GCC, adding parameters `-S -save-temps` makes it leave all intermediate files - preprocessed, assembly, objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't know what is my compiler...there is a way to know it? I simply launch "make" to compile, so the compilator is hidden. Thanks!

Comment: @FlavioBarisi If you could edit in the contents of the Makefile to the question, we would be able to tell what compiler you are using.

Comment: we aren't, because it uses opaque make to compile a kernel module.

Answer (score 0):

```
obj-m := HelloWorld.o

EXTRA_CFLAGS+= -save-temps

all:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.